# The aspect of imperative mood in English

Tags: english, verbs, aspect, mood, imperative

What is the aspect of imperative mood in English?
e.g., Go home!
I know the mood of the verb is imperative here, but I am not sure about the aspect.

Comment: It all depends on what you call ‘aspect’ in English and which set of terminology you use for it. As for what I use, English verbs have 2 aspects, continuous (I _am writing_. I _have been writing_.) and non-continuous  (I _write_. I _have written_.) Since I've never met continuous imperative forms like _*Be writing!_ or _*Be going!_ it looks like in English the imperative mood has no aspect distinction, that's why “Go home!” simply has no aspect at all.

Comment: English doesn't have an inflectional mood system. 'Imperative' is thus a clause type, not a mood form. I'm not aware of the term 'aspect' being applied to imperative clauses.